# Eloquent attribute type casting doesn't work in some models

Tags: laravel, casting, eloquent, lumen

Eloquent attribute casting is awesome, this is great feature that is useful to cast from DB type to native language types.
Boolean in my db is `int(1)`, so I need to cast it to the `bool` type.

I have several models in my application, first model is `User`, and it works like a charm.
1 is converted into true, 0 into false, like I need.

```
class User extends Model {
   protected $table = 'user';
    protected $guarded = ['password','login','id','activationEmail'];
    protected $hidden = [ 'password' ];
 protected $casts = [
        'activationEmail' => 'boolean',
        'activationSMS' => 'boolean',
];
```

Everything is okay here, but I need to do the same trick in another model `NewsArticle`.

```
class NewsArticle extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $casts = [
        'Actual' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

But in this case cast doesn't work at all, I have tried to cast manually and it works, but casts array is ignored at all.

Is there any ideas where the problem can be ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it `Actual` or `actual`?

Comment: it is `Actual` in the database

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have made a mistake in file name of my class model, but the class name itself was correct and it successfully loaded because of some tricks with bootstrap file I have done in order to implement another task.
After file was renamed everything works like expected.